# How to install a minimal version of "lsb_release" on CentOS

Tags: centos, package-management

comming from debian i am currently working with centos7.

i am trying to install the `lsb_release` command, which is quite small.

looking for packages which provide `lsb_release` with

```
yum provides */lsb_release
```

shows me the following packages which provide the package

```
Repo        : epel
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/dkms/lsb_release

redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.i686 : LSB Core module support
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/lsb_release

redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64 : LSB Core module support
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/lsb_release
```

installing it with `yum install redhat-lsb` shows me quite a lot dependencies which i simply don't want and need.

```
Installing for dependencies:
---snip---
emacs-filesystem
---snip---
libXfont
---snip---
mailx
---snip---
```

full list: http://pastie.org/10984474

why centos need for example `mailx` to give me information of the current installed system?

is there some way to install just a minimal `lsb_release` without `*X*`, `qt*`, `gtk2`, `emacs-filesystem`, `desktop-file-utils`, ...

installing it with `yum install dkms` has a much lighter footprint but feels wrong to me and also puts the command in the wrong directory `/usr/lib/dkms/lsb_release` also the dependency of `kernel-devel` is doubtful.

i know there are some alternatives https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-check-centos-version but my question references to the `lsb_release` command.

edit:

also a much smaller footprint has the package `redhat-lsb-core` but it still requires `mailx`

Comment: Nothing wrong with having `mailx` installed. You will probably end up installing it eventually anyway, to read the mail that every system inevitably generates and delivers locally.

Comment: on debian mailx conflicts with postfix, isn't this also the case on centos?

Comment: No, that's not the case at all. Remember that Debian is a rather odd distribution...

Answer (score 2):

The dependencies are because LSB Core specifies for mailx and a few other things to be installed, in turn based on conventions from POSIX. You are installing LSB Core, not just the shell script that prints LSB and distro information.

Some software parses /etc/redhat-release for the version, which isn't standard but is there in EL distros.

Knowing both methods helps identify hosts reliably.